# Polymer template data binding - how to input 2 arguments into a function?

Tags: polymer

I successfully use a single argument in polymer to call a function (in Dart) -eg

```
{{arg1|myfunc}}
```

I can't get two arguments to work. I have tried several combinations, including the example shown on the polymer expressions page:

```
{{ {arg1,arg2} | myfunc}
```

and

```
String myfunc(String arg1, String arg2){
```

but my dart project won't even 'compile' (I get a 404 not found) with that.

What is the correct syntax please? Thanks, Steve

Comment: Can you post some more code? Not sure how this is working into a polymer element. Maybe add `Dart` as a tag too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anthony,

I just tried the **obvious!** Here is the syntax:

```
{{ myfunc(arg1,arg2) }}
```

Steve